# C++ Windows32 GDI Fill Triangle

Tags: c++, windows, gdi

The standard way of FillRect in GDI is

```
Rectangle(hdc, x_, y_, x_ + width_, y_ + height_);
```

But how am i to Fill Triangle ?
How would i approach this without using other resources ?

Comment: As I recall there's a polygon fill. A triangle is a special case of polygon. Or it's probably sufficient to just draw a triangle with a background brush and some filling mode selected.

Comment: You want to *Draw* or to *Fill*? If you want to Fill, you first create a region with CreatePolygonRgn, then use FillRgn to fill it (with some brush).

Answer (score 10):

Use the `Polygon` function, which uses the current brush to fill the polygon.  The following example draws a triangle that is outlined in red and filled with blue:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

...

HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 2, RGB(255, 0, 0));
HPEN hOldPen = SelectPen(hdc, hPen);

HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 255));
HBRUSH hOldBrush = SelectBrush(hdc, hBrush);

POINT vertices[] = { {200, 100}, {300, 300}, {100, 300} };
Polygon(hdc, vertices, sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(vertices[0]));

SelectBrush(hdc, hOldBrush);
DeleteObject(hBrush);

SelectPen(hdc, hOldPen);
DeleteObject(hPen);
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Triangle]